# Pivoting out Datetimes and then calling an operation in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've seen several articles about using datetime and dateutil to convert into datetime objects.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to convert a column into a datetime object so I can pivot out that columns and perform operations against it.

I have a dataframe as such:

```
 Col1   Col 2
   a     1/1/2013
   a     1/12/2013
   b     1/5/2013
   b     4/3/2013  ....etc
```

What I want is :

```
 pivott = pivot_table( df, rows ='Col1', values='Col2', and then I want to get the range of dates for each value in Col1)
```

I am not sure how to correctly approach this. Even after using

```
  df['Col2']= pd.to_datetime(df['Col2'])
```

I couldn't do operations against the dates since they are strings...

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime.strptime

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
convertdatetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d,'%d/%m/%Y')
converted = df['DATE_TIME_IN_STRING'].apply(convertdatetime)
converted[:10] # you should be getting dtype: datetime64[ns]
```